# Script works in Edge but not Chrome

Tags: javascript, json, google-chrome

I have created a simple HTML page which works fine in Edge, but will not run correctly in Chrome.

It is a simple "slideshow" which is loaded into Chrome as a local file from a network drive. There are a series of images which are displayed one at a time. The image list is stored in a separate JSON file and is periodically refreshed, to pick up any new files that have been added. The HTML for the page is then updated with the new image list. Another bit of script looks after the hiding and displaying of the images. As I say, the page is loaded as a local file and not from a server, due to the constraints I am working with. Simply put, I am not an IT professional within my organisation and do not have any ability to create a server on the shared network drive. The purpose of this slideshow is to display information pages on some large screens.

Whilst it all works fine in Edge (my own computer is Windows 10 based, the ones at work that drive the displays are Windows 7 and will be for the next 10 months probably), it would not initially work at all in Chrome, as the JSON would not load. That was solved using a workaround I found on this site, using the switch -allow-file-access-from-files

However, though it appears that the script is now loading the JSON, it will not parse. As I've already hinted, I'm a "hobby programmer", not an IT professional and I'm at a loss to understand why it is not working. Or rather why it works in Edge but not Chrome.

Lots of research has failed to find the answer, probably because I'm not understanding the debugger enough to ask the right question.

I suspect it is something simple I am missing, so here is my code...

```
var xmlhttp;// = new XMLHttpRequest();
var url = "files.json";

initialise();

function initialise() {
    xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
            var myArr = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
            fill(myArr);
        };
    };
    xmlhttp.open("GET", url, true);
    xmlhttp.send();

    function fill(files) {
        var image = [];
        var imageParent = document.getElementById("container");
        var imageElements = document.getElementsByClassName("slides");

        if (files.length > 0 && imageElements.length > 1) {
          while (imageParent.hasChildNodes()) {
            imageParent.removeChild(imageParent.firstChild);
          };
          titleSlide = document.createElement("img");
          titleSlide.className = "slides blank";
          titleSlide.src="";
          titleSlide.id=0;
          titleSlide.style.display="none";
          imageParent.appendChild(titleSlide);
        };

        for (i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
            image[i] = document.createElement("img");
            image[i].className = "slides fade";
            image[i].src = "images\\" + files[i].filename;
            image[i].id = files[i].delay;
            if (i == 0) {
              image[i].style.display="block";
            } else {
              image[i].style.display="none";
            }

            imageParent.appendChild(image[i]);
        };
    };
};
```

The JSON file looks like this:

```
[
    {"filename": "Slide01_05.jpg", "delay": 5},
    {"filename": "Slide02_05.jpg", "delay": 5},
    {"filename": "Slide03_20.jpg", "delay": 20},
    {"filename": "Slide04_15.jpg", "delay": 15},
    {"filename": "Slide05.jpg", "delay": 10},
    {"filename": "Slide06.jpg", "delay": 10}
]
```

In the Chrome debugger, it shows the file successfully "fetched", but even when `this.responsetext` appears to have a value, it does not parse into the array. It can't be too far off being what it should be, as the whole thing works fine in Edge.

Any suggestions?

I'm probably just exposing myself as a complete amateur here...

Many thanks.

Tim

Comment: Check in the network tab if the image paths generated are correct and images are indeed being fetched

Comment: If you're supporting Edge anyway, you should be able to use the `fetch` API. Is your page served by a server, or are you loading the page via a system file path in the browser?

Comment: The image paths are correct. The exact same code works in Edge.

Comment: To clarify, I have created this on my home computer, which is Win 10. The ones at work are Win 7. And no, it is not served, but loaded via a system file path. I'll have a look at the ``fetch`` API - thanks for the tip.

Comment: Have you verified that `this.responseText` actually does have a value (e.g., by logging it to the console)? You say it "appears to" -- so it is not clear.

Comment: And there you have it. I said it appeared to have a value, because hovering over ```this.responseText``` in the debug window showed a value. However, it was never getting to the next line, because the ```this.status``` condition wasn't met.

Comment: Edited the line to ```if (this.readyState == 4) {``` and it now works. Why it worked as it was in Edge is beyond me. Thanks for the tips.